# Limit query on highest value of attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `Teststep` with these columns and values:

```
+----------+----------+---------------+----------+
|   name   | sequence | inner_sequnce | revision |
+----------+----------+---------------+----------+
| Step A   |        1 |             1 |        1 |
| Step B   |        1 |             2 |        1 |
| Step B-2 |        1 |             2 |        2 |
| Step C   |        1 |             3 |        1 |
| Step D   |        2 |             1 |        1 |
+----------+----------+---------------+----------+
```

Now I want all teststeps with `sequence` 1 but only with the highest revision. So in this case it would include `Step A`, `Step B-2` and `Step C`.

The query to get the teststeps with the right `sequence` is easy:

`Teststep.where(sequence: 1)`

But how can I make sure only `Step B-2` is returned and not `Step B` or both `Step B-2` and `Step B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create a subquery and use an aggregate:

```
SELECT * FROM teststeps
WHERE
   teststeps.sequence = 1
AND 
   teststeps.revision = (SELECT MAX(teststeps.revision) WHERE teststeps.sequence = 1)
```

The bad news is that the exact details of how to do this varies depending on which RDBMS is used.

In Rails you could do something like:

```
Teststep.where(sequence: 1)
        .where(revision: Teststep.where(sequence: 1).maximum(:revision))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need!